# Add text to top of DispForm.aspx dependant on specific field value

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, display-form

I need to add the word "Jersey" in red/bold to the top of the Display Form page on a SharePoint online list when 'Jersey' is selected from the 'Location' dropdown field.

Please could you let me know if this is possible? And how I would achieve this? I understand that this could be possible with Javascript however I have limited knowledge of this.

Comment: you can use powerapps

Comment: we would prefer to us javascript if possible as the list is current set to classic experience as we have quite a lot of other javascript embedded on to the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample test demo for your reference(insert script editor webpart into your list display form and insert the script into it).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var location = $("span:contains('Location')").closest('tr').find('#SPFieldChoice')[1].innerText;
            if ($('#customTip').length < 1) {
                var customTip = $('<div id="customTip" style="min-width:300px;color:red;font-weight: bold;text-align:center">' + location + '</div>');
                if (location == "Jersey") {
                    $('table.ms-formtable').parent().prepend(customTip);
                }
            }
        })
    </script>
```

[image]

Update:

Edit form.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var location = $('select[id^="Location"] :selected').text();;
            if ($('#customTip').length < 1) {
                var customTip = $('<div id="customTip" style="min-width:300px;color:red;font-weight: bold;text-align:center">' + location + '</div>');
                if (location == "Jersey") {
                    $('table.ms-formtable').parent().prepend(customTip);
                }
            }
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: That's great thanks Lee. Is it possible to add this to the 'EditForm.aspx' page too? I have tried using the same script, however it doesn't appear to work on the Edit Form.

Comment: Check my update.

Comment: That is perfect, thanks very much Lee!

Answer (score 2):

Add a content editor webpart in your page and add the below code, we are creating an empty `div - lblLocation` and on value change in "Location" drop-down, we get the selected value from the drop-down and setting it to the `div - lblLocation`.

```
<div id="lblLocation" style="font-weight: bold; color: red;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("select[title*='Location']").change(function() {
        $('#lblLocation').append($('option:selected', this).text());        
    }
});
</script>
```